# Running Shells as cronjobs

Tags: shell, cakephp, cron

I am trying to work out how to setup a Shell to run as a cron, I have created a TaskEmailerShell.php file at /app/Console/Command/TaskEmailerShell.php with the following code:

```
App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email');

class TaskEmailerShell extends AppShell {
    public $uses = array('Task');

    public function main()
    {
        // GENERATE AND SEND THE EMAIL
        // ------------------------------------------------------------>
        $email = new CakeEmail();
        etc etc
```

I have followed the instructions [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells/cron-jobs.html) and when the cron runs I get this error:

```
/home/village/public_html/app/Console/cakeshell: line 14: cake: command not found
```

My cron command is:

```
/home/village/public_html/app/Console/cakeshell TaskEmailer -cli /usr/bin -console /Cake/Console -app /home/village/public_html/app >> /home/village/public_html/emailer_log.log
```

Any suggestions where I am going wrong?

Comment: Did you specify how often your code will be executed?

Comment: What's on and near line 14 of `cakeshell`?

Answer (score 1):

The `cakeshell` script you're referring to there requires the `cake` console binary to be somewhere in PATH, or (at least from looking at the usage example), for you to have specified the full path to the Console with the `-console` argument. It looks like you've got a relative path there.

Personally I recommend just calling the cake console directly from your cron job. As other needs arise you may end up writing a script like `cakeshell` to wrap the console. You could try something like :

```
# m h dom mon dow command
*/5 *   *   *   * /home/village/public_html/lib/Cake/Console/cake -app '/home/village/public_html/app/' TaskEmailer >> /home/village/public_html/emailer_log.log
```

Answer (score 1):

`Command not found` usually means your `PATH` is the problem. Programs run from cron might not even have `PATH` set. Any script started by cron must set `PATH` near the beginning or it won't find any of the programs it is supposed to run.

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs at line 14 in the file cakeshell: $cmd. cmd is set at line 4.

```
#!/bin/bash
TERM=dumb
export TERM
cmd="/opt/lampp/htdocs/MyApp/app/Console/cake"
while [ $# -ne 0 ]; do
if [ "$1" = "-cli" ] || [ "$1" = "-console" ]; then
PATH=$PATH:$2
shift
else
cmd="${cmd} $1"
fi
shift
done
$cmd
```

Originally line 4 is

```
cmd="cake"
```

Change it to absolute path like:

```
cmd="/opt/lampp/htdocs/MyApp/app/Console/cake"
```

where MyApp is the application directory. I have faced this problem even after PATH settings. Then mentioning the absolute path solved it.